# MS Access uses a form field in query but prompts for parameter

Tags: ms-access

I have a form with two dependent comboboxes (the second loads its values depending on what is selected in the first one). The second combobox uses this query in its RecordSource property

```
select... where id = [Forms]![MyForm]![myField]
```

My problem is that I choose the myField in the expression builder and so it allegedly generates the bracketed part correctly, but when I run the form Access doesn't understand it and always prompts for a parameter named with that expression [Forms]!...etc.

Comment: Try specifying the field only: `select... where id = [myField]`.

Comment: Hum... It worked. Seems a little strange, but if I think it makes sense. Maybe you should not use a full form expression because if you want to use a value from another form it's better to pass it to your current one, and that's the context for the [myfield]". Perhaps the full expression is a deprecated format. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved as per post comments by Gustav:

> Try specifying the field only: `select... where id = [myField]`.

Comment: I can add, that I never use the expression builder. It has always appeared flaky to me, and this is just another example.